# How to get and set TemplateBinding of a property in code in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controltemplate, templatebinding

I have a textblock with a `TemplateBinding`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
```

It might seem weird but to spare you the details, I need to retrieve this `TemplateBinding` of `Text` property in the C# code, save it to a variable temporarily, and then assign it back to the same `Text` property. 
How can I do that?

So far I've tried these to get `TemplateBinding`:

```
//First approach
BindingExpression bindingExpression = textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;

//Second approach
BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty);
```

They don't work, probably because they retrieve only regular binding not `TemplateBinding`

Comment: Make it a regular Binding with `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`?

Comment: @Clemens Can you please be more specific what you mean?

Comment: Replace `{TemplateBinding Text}` by `{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`.